# Find the maximum number of times a word appears in a 2D-matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, multidimensional-array, backtracking

A 2-D grid of characters is given. For e.g. A 5x4 matrix is as follows :

```
{{'M','O','B','S','N'},
{'M','O','I','L','E'},
{'M','B','I','L','E'},
{'O','B','I','L','E'}}.
```

I have to find how many times the word "MOBILE" occurs in above grid using Java. For above the answer would be 3. I can traverse only in 4 directions, i.e. right, left, up, down. (NOT DIAGONALLY).

Another example :

```
                   {{'c','a','r'},
                   {'a','r','c'},
                   {'c','r','a'}}
```

and the word is "car". Answer for this grid would be 5.

I am aware of the fact that backtracking would help but HOW?

Comment: Looks like a homework question. Did you try anything? In this form, this question is not a good fit for StackOverflow (more like: "I am looking for a freelancer to implement this code for me").

Answer (score 0):

If matrix has N elements, search string is k chars, there are m copies in matrix:

First, find all positions of first letter of string in matrix. O(N)

Then for each found position, do 4-way scan for n-1 characters. O(k*m)

Finally, sum all search results. O(m)

Answer (score 0):

Following is the solution to my own question. It took me a while to figure out.
P.S. I've developed the solution ignoring any possibility of pallindromes.

```
import java.util.*;

class WOG{

static int m = 0;
static int n = 0;
static int[] x = {0,-1,0,1};
static int[] y = {-1,0,1,0};

public static int func(char[][] grid, int row, int col, String word, int k, int[][]g2){

int occ = 0;

if(row>=m || row<0 || col<0 || col>=n)
    return 0;

if(grid[row][col]!=word.charAt(k))
    return 0;
    
if(k==word.length()-1)
    return 1;

if(g2[row][col]==0)
    return 0;

g2[row][col] = 0;

for(int dir=0;dir<4;dir++){

    int rd = row+x[dir];
    int cd = col+y[dir];

    
    occ += func(grid,rd,cd,word,k+1,g2);
}

return occ;

}

public static int pattern(char[][] grid, String word){

int res = 0;

int[][] g2 = new int[m][n];
for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        g2[i][j]=-1;
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        res += func(grid,i,j,word,0,g2);
    }
}

return res;

}

public static void main(String[] args){
    
    char[][] grid2 = {{'m','o','b','s','n'},
              {'m','o','i','l','e'},
              {'m','b','i','l','e'},
              {'o','b','i','l','e'}};

    char[][] grid = {{'c','a','r'},
             {'a','r','c'},
             {'c','r','a'}};

    char[][] grid3 = {{'b','a'},
              {'y','c'}};

    m = 2;
    n = 2;
    int ans = pattern(grid3,"baby");
    System.out.println(ans);
}
}
```

I've made use of recursion and backtracking.
Edit : I've placed a new 2x2 grid g2, which acts as a visit verifier. If for a word, a character has already been visited in the grid, it won't be visited again. So, this solves the problem of pallindromes.

Comment: Your algorithm finds `baby` in `{{'b','a'}, {'y', 'c'}}`. Is it intended?

Comment: Oh, that's because baby contains "bab" and I've ignored the case of palindrome. So, let's assume that it was intentional. To avoid this problem, I must have taken care of not repeating a preceding direction in succeeding character, but I struggled in finding the solution to that.